# Warning CS7022 - The entry point of the program is global code; ignoring 'Program.Main(string[])' entry point

Tags: c#-9.0

I have an issue where I have this warning in my *Error List*:

```
Severity Code   Description                     Project File                Line  Suppression State
Warning  CS7022 The entry point of the program  Project DirectoryToProject  23    Active
                is global code; ignoring
                'Program.Main(string[])'
                entry point.
```

This is essentially where it’s throwing:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) => await new Program.MainAsync();
    }
        static async Task MainAsync()
        {.. do stuff.. }
}
```

That is the line of code that is causing the error. I've tried playing around with the Main class. I did have it with the return type void and had my GetAwaiter and GetResult method called on the MainAsync method.

I've tried researching the error, but I didn’t have any luck, so hopefully, this question will help a few others...

I am currently running on C# 9.0,
Visual Studio 2019 Build Version: 16.8.30717.126

The MainAsync was in the file... I’m trying to limit the amount of methods I show as 95% of them aren't useful the to question... But the issue is that although my application compiles, when executing my program it quits instantly as if it doesn't know where to start...

If anyone experiences something like this, try what Hans Passant mentioned:

> "This is a rather awful C# v9 feature. Menu *Project* → *Properties* → *Build tab, Advanced button* → *Language version = 7.3*. You should now get a decent error message from the code you didn't know you had to post".

Essentially upon changing back to C# 8.0, I saw it was a different file hidden away causing the issue.

Comment: This is a rather awful C# v9 feature.  Project > Properties > Build tab, Advanced button > Language version = 7.3  You should now get a decent error message from the code you didn't know you had to post.

Comment: @HansPassant Fantastic... That worked, it was a different file messing it up which was an empty JSON file... Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can happen if a file (any file) in the project has global code, that's to say statements outside of a class.

Comment: It was a json file that was empty which caused the issue

Comment: this was my issue

Answer (score 35):

Starting with .NET 5.0, I've found that this error can be caused by having stray semicolons above the namespace keyword. Whether this is a bug or intended behavior is beyond me, however make sure you don't have any standalone semicolons as such:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
; // This will cause CS7022

namespace Tomoe.Commands.Public
```

Be sure to check all your files and not just `Program.cs`

Apparently this is intended behavior; see *[Stray semicolon above namespace keyword causes warning CS7022 and unexpected exit #53472](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/53472)*.

TL;DR, semicolons above namespaces are interpreted as top level statements. Because nothing is being called in said statement, the program exits. This is the same as doing

```cs
static void Main() {
    ;
}
```

in your `Program.cs`. While I do feel some change should be made, the design decision behind this is quite logical and entirely understandable.

According to [jcouv on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/53472#issuecomment-866502606), this is now becoming an error instead of a warning. Hopefully, this "bug" shall harass us no more!

Comment: Moreover it seems like having unneeded `using` statements even causes this...

Comment: Can't believe it was a stray semi-colon that resulted in a wasted hour. This happened when I switched .net version from 3.1 to 5 in my asp.net core project. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, exactly that semicolon

Comment: Filed a bug report over on their main repo: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6263

Comment: I am dealing with this. I am migrating a system to .NET 5 I already tried looking for all semicolons. I also changed the names of other methods called "Main" of the system. I also found that many `@using` were defined after `@model` in the Razor Pages. The CS7022 error is still there.

Comment: For me it was empty braces {} just under the using

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by others, this is caused by a new C# 9 feature that is called "[Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)". This Feature enables you to write statements in the global context and the compiler will create it's own Main() based on that.

In my case I had a semicolon after my using statements in any of my files. As far as I know Visual Studio or the compiler don't give you any option to find this "entry-point" without changing any settings as descripted by others in this thread.
My solution was to just create another "Top-level statement entry point" in my project. Due to the fact that there is only one allowed the compiler complains about that.
I just added a semicolon directly after the using statements in my Program.cs. Because this file is one of the first that are processed by the compiler any other file that contains a "Top-level statement" will cause an error.

Answer (score 3):

I've also seen this compiler error in the following scenario. You've written your code with top-level statements. Later, you decide to absorb that logic into a `Main()` method. (Maybe you find you now need to return an `async Task`, or you need to modify it to meet a company coding standard, for example.) Even though the following code block will compile (in VS2022 at least), it generates the error in question with a green squiggly beneath `Main`:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside the Main() method");
    //Do some other work here
}
```

Where's the issue? The method declaration is correct, and it will run, but even when this is the only code in the `Program.cs` file, and even when no other entry point is specified in the project/solution settings, we do not get the expected output:

[image: Debug console output]

Even the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements) isn't much help in this case, because it pretty much repeats in more detail what the error is saying.

What's missing is the `Program` class definition. Without it, the compiler is still looking for a top-level statement - which it finds, namely `static void`. Then the next thing it finds is the `Main()` method declaration, but it finds this after the (unintended) top-level statement `static void`. Hence, the error sorta makes sense now.

The fix is to wrap the above code in a Program class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside the Main() method");
    }
}
```

And now we get the expected output:

[image: Revised code output]

Comment: No idea why this is not upvoted. While the other answers are correct, this is the most comprehensive answer for a clueless guy!