# C# warning CS7022

Tags: c#

I am learning C#, I've purchased the book **C# 11 and .NET 7**, I have an iMAC running macOS Monterey Version 12.7 and I have Visual Studio Code Version 1.83.0 (Universal).

I have installed the plugins for C# and my simple program is:

```
namespace HelloWorld {
    class Hello {
        public static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world");  
        }
    }
}
```

In a terminal I build with:

```
dotnet new console -o HelloCS --force
```

This results in the output:

```
The template "Console App" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Restoring /Users/sy/cs11dotnet7/Chapter01-vscode/HelloCS/HelloCS/HelloCS.csproj:
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
Restore succeeded.
```

I run the program with:

```
dotnet run
```

The output:

```
/Users/sy/cs11dotnet7/Chapter01-vscode/HelloCS/Program.cs(3,28): warning CS7022: The entry point of the program is global code; ignoring 'Hello.Main()' entry point. [/Users/sy/cs11dotnet7/Chapter01-vscode/HelloCS/HelloCS.csproj]
Hello, World!
```

I've searched online for a solution to CS7022 and I cannot see anything that would explain why I am seeing this, what is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning CS7022 - The entry point of the program is global code; ignoring 'Program.Main(string\[\])' entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045746/warning-cs7022-the-entry-point-of-the-program-is-global-code-ignoring-progra)

Comment: Can you describe clearly what the steps you took? Which file and directory is `class Hello` in? Did you run `dotnet new console -o HelloCS --force` after writing that file?

Comment: The correct order should be, use `dotnet new` to create the project, load that directory in VS Code, edit the `Program.cs`, then run it with `dotnet run`

Comment: @Sweeper, there is only a single file Program.cs.  Please re-read my post it shows quite clearly the steps I took.

Comment: @Martheen, thank you thats fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new console app using `dotnet new console`, there will be a file produced that contains `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");`, this line is included on its own and there is no surrounding method/class declarations.

This is what is so called top-level programs or top-level statements. It's a C# 9 feature that simplifies the code needed. The compiler then will wrap the top-level statements into a "synthesized" entrypoint method and class declaration.

For your case, it seems you have both, top-level statements and an explicit `Main` declaration. So the compiler is telling you this:

> hey, I'm confused at which code should be your entry point. You have both top-level statements and an explicit `Main` method declaration. I'm gonna use the top-level statements one and ignore your explicit `Main` declaration.

Comment: When I execute dotnet new console, the content of Program.cs is reduced to just: 
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Comment: Trying to run it after building results in:

Comment: /Users/sy/cs11dotnet7/Chapter01-vscode/HelloCS/Program.cs(2,1): error CS8802: Only one compilation unit can have top-level statements. [/Users/sy/cs11dotnet7/Chapter01-vscode/HelloCS/HelloCS.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
sy@Simons-iMac HelloCS %

Comment: Yes, that is because you have two code files, one with top-level statements (created from dotnet new, and the other one you wrote yourself)

Comment: I can see that there are two files...both with the same name and both with different content, why is that?  Two files called Program.cs one in the project folder and another in a sub-folder of the project folder.

Comment: There is one you created yourself, and the other is created by `dotnet new` command you executed. Both files are passed to the compiler, and both are containing valid entrypoint candidate. So the compiler is telling you I'm going to use the entrypoint from the top-level statements file. That is all it.